# drag & drop script started crashing after css changed

Tags: javascript, css, html, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a `div` drag and drop certain places. It worked fine, but then I changed the `css` and now it started crashing the `javascript` and I don't seems to be able to find the reason in the `css`.

Any clue on how to fix this?

```
<style>
    .targetBox{
    width: 10em; 
        height: 10em; 
        -webkit-border-radius: 5em; 
        -moz-border-radius: 5em;
        border-radius: 5em;
        border:3px dashed black;
        float:left;
    }

    .imageBox{
        width: 10em; 
        height: 10em;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5em; 
        -moz-border-radius: 5em;
        border-radius: 5em;
        padding:1px;
        border:1px solid #aaaaaa; 
        background-color:red;
    }

    .imageBox-wrapper{
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        margin:auto;
        top:25em;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
</script>

<div>
    <div class="targetBox" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="targetBox" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="targetBox" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>

<div class="imageBox-wrapper">
    <div class="imageBox" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
Created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eBsqJ/1/). Don't know if it's because the break happens, but for some reason the fiddle doesn't show the drag animation I see in my VS project.

Comment: try creating a fiddle of your problem..!!

Comment: @SajadLfc there you go ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is broken is because you are declaring the `drag` function after the HTML is referencing `drag`.

You will need to move your JS code up (try placing it in a seperate file, and 'ing it before anything in your

**Part 2**: The reason why your code fails is because you have not set an ID for the element to be dragged. Set an ID for the element, and it will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/eBsqJ/2/

Comment: edited the fiddle. didn't solve the main problem, did solve the drag animation in the fiddle ;-)

Comment: You didn't set an ID for the red circle. See my updated answer  for a working iddle.